# Kafka HA consumer setup

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My application consumes a messages from kafka topic which is working fine when I have a single instance running in my environment but if I run multiple instances lets say 3 instances (High Availability) then none of the instance of my application able to consume messages from topic.

I have 3 partition on that topic and 1 replication factor.

When I run

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic mytesttopic

Topic:mytesttopic     PartitionCount:3        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
    Topic: mytesttopic    Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
    Topic: mytesttopic    Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
    Topic: mytesttopic    Partition: 2    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

It gives me above configuration for mytesttopic. So I am not sure which steps missing here to consume message from Kafka in HA or multiple instances of consumers.

Comment: Need few more details.

Output of the command ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group domain-fetching-job
KafkaConsumer Configuration

Comment: Also when you said "none of the instance of my application able to consume messages from topic", are there any errors ? Anything in the logs with log4j trace ?

Answer (score 0):

You should validate that all of your Kafka brokers instances are registered on the Zookeeper and of course have different `broker.id`.

You can do it by running this: `/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids`

After creating a new topic with 3 partition and running your `describe` command you should get the following output:

```
Topic: mytesttopic   PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1    Configs:
Topic: mytesttopic   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
Topic: mytesttopic   Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: mytesttopic   Partition: 2    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
```